# How can I redirect www to to non-www domain

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

I need `www.mydomain.com` to permanently redirect to `mydomain.com`

I am having problems doing this mainly because most answers say to use `urlRewriter` but I can't try this because I can't test it with `www.localhost:port`.

I don't want to put it straight in the production environment.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need `localhost:port`? Use your hosts file to set an arbitrary domain for `localhost` and configure your Tomcat correctly to run on the correct ports. You can also set up an VM that is identical to your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Route53 ALIAS records to create zone apex records (without www) referencing AWS resources (Load Balancers, Buckets, Distributions,...) directly: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html